# Chrome Extension Get The Current Domain On Every Tab Change

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dns, location

I am trying to get the current domain and alert it on every tab change with chrome extension. For example everytime the user navigates another page it will `alert("your current path is: " + location.hostname);` But it does not work. What i am doing wrong? I tried this code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    alert(location.hostname);
);
```

Answer (score 1):

That wont work because the `location.hostname` of a background page is a chrome:// extension url.

add

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

then change your code to:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(){
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {//get current tab without any selectors
        alert(tab.url);  //get tab value 'url'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

send hostname request to content script

in background.js:

```
// record active tab id when user switch tab every time
// activeTabId is global variable
var activeTabId = undefined;
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(
    function(activeInfo){
        activeTabId = activeInfo.tabId;
    }
);

// send hostname request to content script when user update active tab
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(
    function(changeInfo,tab){
        // check if the updating tab is active tab
        if(tab.id === activeTabId){
            // send hostname request
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTabId,{alertHostName:true});
        }
    }
);
```

in ContentScript.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if (request.hasOwnProperty("alertHostName")){
            if(Boolean(request.alertHostName)){
                alert(location.hostname);
            }
        }
    }
);
```